# Node.js service unable to connect RabbitMQ on AKS

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, rabbitmq

I have a Node.js application that is *containerized* and deployed on [AKS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/intro-kubernetes).

I also have [RabbitMQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RabbitMQ) deployed on the same cluster and available on `queuename.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local:5672`

It works fine when it is containerized with a normal Dockerfile like this:

```
# Install Node.js
FROM node:20.2.0-alpine3.16

# stage 1 for dev
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/dist
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "start" ]
```

But when I optimize it with a **non-root user, and a different port**, it is not able to connect to the RabbitMQ and throws this error:

```
/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("647db632e239b362ce8649ac"),
    "serviceName" : "nodejs-service",
    "controllerName" : "RabbitMQService",
    "methodName" : "connectToRabbitMQ",
    "message" : "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ.",
    "exception" : "Error: Expected amqp: or amqps: as the protocol; got \n    at connect (D:\\LyveCloud-11-04-23\\nodejs-service\\node_modules\\amqplib\\lib\\connect.js:171:11)\n
    "logLevel" : "Error",
    "severity" : "Critical",
    "request" : null,
    "response" : null,
    "statusCode" : "400",
```

No change except the change in Dockerfile which is as follows:

```
# Install Node.js
FROM node:20.2.0-alpine3.16

# stage 1 for dev
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/dist
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

# Create a non-root user and group
RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -u 1001 -G appgroup
# Set ownership of necessary directories
RUN chown -R appuser:appgroup /usr/src/app
# Set user and group for the container
USER appuser:appgroup
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "start" ]
```

What could be the reason of this and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Have you added the protocol as part of the URL - `amqps://queuename.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local:5672`?

Comment: yes, the protocol is part of the URL and being passed as an ENV at the time of deployment through a Helm Chart. 
Could it be an issue with that protocol not being accessible to the non root user?

Comment: You can just log the URL before connecting to Rabbitmq to see what's getting passed to it.

Comment: I am not changing that part of the deployment where RabbitMQ address is being injected in the container. It is same for both the scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pointing to this section of code in the amqp lib:

```
    "exception" : "Error: Expected amqp: or amqps: as the protocol; 
         got \n    at connect (D:\\LyveCloud-11-04-23\\nodejs- 
         service\\node_modules\\amqplib\\lib\\connect.js:171:11)\n
```

Which is https://github.com/amqp-node/amqplib/blob/main/lib/connect.js#L171:

```
if (protocol === 'amqp:') {
    sock = require('net').connect(sockopts, onConnect);
  }
  else if (protocol === 'amqps:') {
    sock = require('tls').connect(sockopts, onConnect);
  }
  else {
    throw new Error("Expected amqp: or amqps: as the protocol; got " + protocol);
  }
```

The error seems to suggest a prefix other than amqps:// or ampq:// was received in the URL. In fact the error message outputs the `protocol` it picked up but nothing appears after the `got` token in the error message suggesting no protocol was picked up from the url specified.

```
throw new Error("Expected amqp: or amqps: as the protocol; got " + ****protocol****);
```

Perhaps you need to escape some chars or one was not set?